# Plugin bootstrap-material-datetimepicker desativar dias da semana

Tags: jquery, datetime, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Estou a usar o plugin de Timepicker chamado bootstrap-material-datetimepicker:

(https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker).

Gostaria de conseguir desativar alguns dia da semana, ou só ativar as quartas-feiras e sextas-feiras mas não estou a conseguir, alguém me da uma ajuda? obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ### Atualização
>
> Fiz um  pull request para adicionar esta opção ao plugin, os autores validaram e adicionaram a versão que já esta disponível na data
>   04/05/2016.
>
> [Add option to enable especific days #98](https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/pull/98)

Como o pessoal acima citou, não existe este comportamento,mas você pode facilmente customizar e adicionar os teus comportamentos a qualquer plugin, basta entender como é o funcionamento.

**Exemplo:**

Passe por parâmetro  os dias que permaneceram habilitados.

```
$('#date').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
      time: false,
      clearButton: true,
      enableDays: [3, 5]
});
```

Começando pelo índice 0  [3,5] são equivalentes a Quarta e Sexta.

Agora abra o arquivo: *`bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js`*

Adicione o seguinte comportamento:

```
enableDays: function() {
  var enableDays = this.params.enableDays;
  if (enableDays) {
    $(".dtp-picker-days tbody tr td").each(function() {
      if (!(($.inArray($(this).index(), enableDays)) >= 0)) {
        $(this).find('a').css({
          "background": "#e3e3e3",
          "cursor": "no-drop",
          "opacity": "0.5"
        }).off("click");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora você precisa acionar este comportamento quando a modal abrir,neste exemplo adicionei no final do `onFocus`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Gabriel, obrigado pela ajuda, mas agora reparei que ao clicar uma vez ele realmente aparece com os dias da semana bloqueados mas se eu andar para a frente no calendário eles desbloqueiam todos sendo possível selecionar os dias, sabes o que possa ser? obrigado mais uma vez

Comment: @LaranjaMecânica Sei sim, lembra que instanciei ela no evento on focus? Agora você precisa apenas declara-la no evento de transição

Comment: Obrigado mais um vez, perfeito :D

Answer (score 1):

Esse plugin não oferece suporte a essa funcionalidade. Para fazer isso é necessário alterar o código do plugin ou buscar outra alternativa.
Fiz uma alteração na função constructHTMLCalendar do plugin para realizar essa verificação que você solicitou:

```js
constructHTMLCalendar: function(date, calendar)  {
var _template = "";

...
if(calendar.days[i] != 0)
{
 if(this.isBeforeMaxDate(moment(calendar.days[i]), false, false) === false || this.isAfterMinDate(moment(calendar.days[i]), false, false) === false)
 {
  _template += '<span class="dtp-select-day">' + moment(calendar.days[i]).locale(this.params.lang).format("DD") + '</span>';
 }
 else
 {
  var quarta = 3;
  var sexta = 5;
   if(moment(calendar.days[i]).locale(this.params.lang).format("DD") === moment(this.currentDate).locale(this.params.lang).format("DD"))
   {
    if(new Date(calendar.days[i]._d).getDay() == quarta || new Date(calendar.days[i]._d).getDay() == sexta){
     _template += '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dtp-select-day selected">' + moment(calendar.days[i]).locale(this.params.lang).format("DD") + '</a>'; 
    }else{
     _template += '<a class="selected">' + moment(calendar.days[i]).locale(this.params.lang).format("DD") + '</a>';
    }
   }
   else
   {
    if(new Date(calendar.days[i]._d).getDay() == quarta || new Date(calendar.days[i]._d).getDay() == sexta){
     _template += '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dtp-select-day">' + moment(calendar.days[i]).locale(this.params.lang).format("DD") + '</a>';
    }else{
     _template += '<a disabled="disabled">' + moment(calendar.days[i]).locale(this.params.lang).format("DD") + '</a>'; 
    }
   }
 }

  _template += '</td>';
 }
}
_template += '</tr></tbody></table>';

return _template;
},
```

Você pode observar que criei duas variáveis quarta e sexta e utilizo elas no if para remover ou não a classe 'dtp-select-day' (que é utilizada pra identificar os dias que podem ser selecionados) e o href do dia que está sendo construído no calendário. Se você quiser pode aplicar no seu bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js e vê se isso te atende.

Answer (score 1):

Usando **Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 do *eonasdan***, eles já implementam a funcionalidade para desativar datas especificas, para o usuario não selecionar.

Segue o plugin: 
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

*Enabled/Disabled Dates*

```
$('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
   defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
   disabledDates: [
      moment("12/25/2013"),
      new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
      "11/22/2013 00:53"
    ]
});
```

Neste caso, está desativado as datas 21 e 22 do mês 11 do Ano 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Olhando a documentação no Git deles, eles não possuem essa funcionalidade. O que você pode fazer é abrir um "issue" para eles:
https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/issues

Até lá, o que você pode fazer é procurar outra ferramenta ou aguardar a resposta deles.

Aqui tem alguns exemplos de outras ferramentas:

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker

https://github.com/ripjar/material-datetime-picker